# MYSQL - error while selecting date range

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I got an error while selecting between dates of different month and using date_format in the query.

I have a record with timestamp column named 'call_date' and the value is '2014-02-26 13:33:20'.

When I run:

```
SELECT * FROM survey_answer WHERE DATE_FORMAT(call_date,'%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN '22/02/2014' AND '28/02/2014'
```

The result is the line what I expected.

But, if I run:

```
SELECT * FROM survey_answer WHERE DATE_FORMAT(call_date,'%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN '22/02/2014' AND '01/03/2014'
```

There is no results.

Comment: Why are you taking a date and then converting it to a string for comparison purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that the internal format of MySQL concerning dates is `YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS` and not `DD-MM-YYYY`. If you change it accordingly, it should work.

```
SELECT *
FROM survey_answer
WHERE call_date > "2014-02-22 00:00:00" AND 
  call_date < "2014-03-01 23:59:59"
```

You also [do not want to use `BETWEEN` on timestamps](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).

Comment: Right.. That is the way I followed.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your query will not use indexes, since you using functoin on field in condition.

```
SELECT * 
FROM survey_answer 
WHERE call_date BETWEEN '2014-02-22' AND '2014-02-25'
```

You can format date on client side.